# How to add an instance method in Sequelize model

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I would like to add an instance method to `Sequelize` `User` model with `postgres`.  `User` model is defined as below:

```
const Sql = require('sequelize');
const db = require("../startup/db");

const User = db.define('user', {
    id: {type: Sql.INTEGER,
         primaryKey:true,
         min: 1},
    name: {type: Sql.STRING,
           allowNull: false,
           min: 2,
           max: 50
        },
    email: {type: Sql.STRING,
            isEmail: true},       
    encrypted_password: {type: Sql.STRING,
                         min: 8},
    createdAt: Sql.DATE,
    updatedAt: Sql.DATE
});
```

I am looking for something like this in model `User`:

```
User.instanceMethods.create(someMethod => function() {
   //method code here
   });
```

The instance method can be access like this:

```
let user = new User();
user.someMethod();
```

There is `Instance` for model in `Sequelize` but it was not for the instance method. What is the right way to add instance method in `Sequelize` model?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is the answer for the question. See reply by `Mariano`.

[Cannot access Sequelize instance methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43954112/cannot-access-sequelize-instance-methods)

Here is more reading:
https://codewithhugo.com/using-es6-classes-for-sequelize-4-models/

Comment: So the user user938363 posts a question. And then he adds a simple link as an "answer". And then he decides that his link is the proper answer, despite the fact that another user (Ugo Giordano) posted an actual answer with useful working code below. Uhmm, interesting!

Answer (score 8):

```
const User = db.define('user', {
    id: {type: Sql.INTEGER,
         primaryKey:true,
         min: 1},
    name: {type: Sql.STRING,
           allowNull: false,
           min: 2,
           max: 50
        },
    email: {type: Sql.STRING,
            isEmail: true},       
    encrypted_password: {type: Sql.STRING, min: 8},
    createdAt: Sql.DATE,
    updatedAt: Sql.DATE
});


// This is an hook function
User.beforeSave((user, options) => {
   // Do something
});

// This is a class method
User.classMethod = function (params) {
    // Do something with params
}

// This is an instance method
User.prototype.instanceMethod = function (params) {
    // Do something with params
}
```

Comment: This should be selected as the real answer of the question. And not the link posted by the owner of the question.